# What would be a RESTful URL pattern for a date range?

Tags: rest

As I understand it, RESTful URL is more like a resource locator than a command. For example, to get user 1234, you wouldn't use this:

```
//Not restful
https://server/GetUser?UserID=1234
```

You would use this:

```
//Restful
https://server/users/1234
```

This makes sense for resources that take a single identifier.

But what if I want to get, say, a range of transactions between two dates?

```
//Old style
https://server/GetTransactions?StartDate=2020-02-20&EndDate=2020-02-21
```

What would a RESTful URL look like?

Comment: Please use ISO dates: 2020-02-20 and 2020-02-21

Comment: Why not timestamps?

Comment: There's a subtle - but key difference here between the two examples. In the `User` case, 1234 is the id of the specific `User` resource you want, and that's perfectly in-line with `REST` guidelines. However, in the second, the object is *really* `Transactions` and you are not specifying an identity, you are specifying a *filter* on the Transactions resource. And (for good reason) `REST` doesn't specify how this should be done because it's not really a concern it was ever intended to address. So in effect, your url is fine and RESTful  like this: `GET /server/Transactions?StartDate=2020-02-20`

Answer (score 2):

As you already have found out, REST has semantics for locating an object and all objects. There is no standard for querying, sorting, or pagination. Often, the query string is used. However, there are a couple of disadvantages: The URL can get really hard to read, information may leak into logs, and there may be length limits.

If it goes just beyond a simple use case (and it will eventually) I would POST a search request with the request parameters in the body.

Answer (score 2):

> What would be a RESTful URL pattern for a date range?

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI.  A URI is an *identifier*; general-purpose components are not using infer semantics.

That's an important property, because it allows a server to encode any arbitrary data that it needs to into the identifier.

```
//Old style
https://server/GetTransactions?StartDate=2/20/2020&EndDate=2/21/2020
```

That's a perfectly satisfactory spelling - key value pairs that are application/x-www-form-urlencoded and then applied as a query string is one of the oldest forms of [URI template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) on the web.  Furthermore, it turns out that style of URI is very convenient when using HTML to collect the parameters.

If you look carefully at [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), you'll see that the section on level 4 templates includes other ways of describing an encoding of key-value pairs into a URI.  That would allow you to encode them into a path segment, rather than into the query part, which could be useful if you wanted to append additional path segments.

So you could instead try something like

```
https://server/GetTransactions/StartDate=2%2F20%2F2020,EndDate=2%2F21%2F2020
```

Notice the encoding of the solidus to ensure that the date parts remain together when the path segments are parsed.

`GetTransactions` is a bit soft -- it doesn't *matter*, in the sense that general purpose components don't care.  But when we are exercising our discretion in producing identifiers that humans will understand, it's usually the case that we want to align the identifier with the *resource*; we're identifying the thing described by the representation.

Which is to say, resources are the result sets, not the queries.

Compare

```
/GetTransactions?Year=2019
/AnnualReport?Year=2019
```

For ranges where you want to make the start time and end time explicit, you might consider [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which not only gives you a date representation without using solidus ([2020-02-20](https://xkcd.com/1179/)), but also several explicit representations of [time intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals)

Comment: Just to add if he wanted transactions can be viewed as resources/entities thus he could use `https://server/Transactions?StartDate=2/20/2020&EndDate=2/21/2020
`

Answer (score 2):

Although it depends on your requirements, domain, context and size of the data, one way to make it restful is,

```
https://server/transactions/start/2020-02-20/end/2020-02-21
```

So I will have flexibility of filtering like,

```
https://server/transactions/start/2020-02-20
```

For the above query I will return all transactions that starts with date `2020-02-20` till last.

```
https://server/transactions/end/2020-02-21
```

For the above query I will return all transactions that starts from the beginning till date `2020-02-21`